# How does one, for an array of user items, merge the entries of consecutive user items where user name and an additional sole property name are equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, reduce

Let say an array with inconsistent properties like the following :

```
[
    {user: 'user1', comment: 'This is a comment',},
    {user: 'user1', role: 'member'},
    {user: 'user1', role: 'writer'},
    {user: 'user2', role: 'admin'},
    {user: 'user1', comment: 'This is another comment'},
]
```

How to turn it so the objects will be grouped **only
if the next element in the array has the same property and belongs to the same user** :

```
[
    {user: 'user1', comment: 'This is a comment'},
    {user: 'user1', role: [{'member', 'writer'}]},
    {user: 'user2', role: 'admin'},
    {user: 'user1', comment: 'This is another comment'},
]
```

Comment: The merged user data of `user1` of cause has to look like this ... `{ user: 'user1', role: ['member', 'writer'] },` ... hasn't it?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution too, is implemented as a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

The iterating task works with a lookbehind approach, comparing the current user item to the previous one. If both matching criteria (same user name and same property name) are met the process tries to look up an already existing `merger` object which would be referred to via the `collector` object. In case a previous merger did not happen a new `merger` object gets created from the previous user item and assigned to the `collector`. In any case the merger would be aggregated by the currently processed user item.

```js
function mergeConsecutiveSameSoleUserEntry(collector, userItem, idx, arr) {
  let { merger, result } = collector;
  let isProceedUnmerged = true;

  if (idx >= 1) {
    const { user: userName, ...soleEntry } = userItem;
    const { user: prevUserName, ...prevSoleEntry } = arr[idx - 1] ?? {};

    if (userName === prevUserName) {
      const [soleKey, soleValue] = Object.entries(soleEntry).at(0);
      const [prevSoleKey, prevSoleValue] = Object.entries(prevSoleEntry).at(0);

      if (soleKey === prevSoleKey) {
        if (!merger) {

          merger = collector.merger = {
            user: userName,
            [soleKey]: [prevSoleValue],
          };
          result[result.length - 1] = merger;
        }
        merger[soleKey].push(soleValue);
        
        isProceedUnmerged = false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (isProceedUnmerged) {
    Reflect.deleteProperty(collector, 'merger');

    result.push(userItem);
  }
  return collector;
}

console.log([

  { user: 'user1', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'member' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'This is another comment' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'And this is yet another comment' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'Yet another comment' },

].reduce(mergeConsecutiveSameSoleUserEntry, { result: [] }).result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive function like this

```js
let data = [
  { user: 'user1', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'member' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'This is another comment' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'And this is yet another comment' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'Yet another comment' },
];
let combined = []

const combineRole = (curr, next, data) => {
  if (curr.user == next?.user && curr.role && next.role) {
    curr.role = [curr.role, next.role].flat().filter(Boolean)
    return combineRole(curr, data.shift(), data)
  } else {
    return [curr, next]
  }
}

while (data.length) {
  // console.log(data)
  let [curr, next] = (combineRole(data.shift(), data.shift(), data))
  if (next)
    data.unshift(next)
  combined.push(curr)
}
console.log(combined)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AlyaKra ... did the OP or maybe the author of the above approach even check the example code's result? In case the OP was clear about the requirements, the above result does not even come close to what was/is expected. How can one upvote/accept (or provide/post) code without counterchecking?

Comment: @PeterSeliger it was a very small mistake that I have updated, i.e. not checking if role key is present in the object. I think the approach above is much cleaner and readable than what you've given. Also "not even come close to what was/is expected" is a very petty exaggeration

Comment: *code review* ... the update did not entirely fix the issue (thus the return value still does not match the expectations). The code e.g. checks hardcoded for just a `role` property. But the entry provided in addition to  the standard `user` entry ... `{ user: 'userName' /*, just one more entry */ }` ... can be anything according to the OP. Check with the updated test data. btw ... the recursive approach with its `data` argument resembles a `reduce` task.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reduce to make something like that

```js
const datas = [
  { user: 'user1', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'member' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'This is a comment' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'writer' },
  { user: 'user2', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'admin' },
  { user: 'user1', role: 'observer' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'This is another comment' },
  { user: 'user3', comment: 'And this is yet another comment' },
  { user: 'user2', comment: 'Yet another comment' },
];

const datas2 = datas.reduce((s, d, x) => {
  if (x > 0) {
    const dk = Object.keys(d)
    if (dk.join(',') === Object.keys(s[s.length - 1]).join(',') && d.user === s[s.length - 1].user) {
      for (const k in dk) {
        if (dk[k] !== 'user' && d.hasOwnProperty(dk[k]) && s[s.length - 1].hasOwnProperty(dk[k])) {
          if (typeof s[s.length - 1][dk[k]] !== 'object')
            s[s.length - 1][dk[k]] = [s[s.length - 1][dk[k]]]
          s[s.length - 1][dk[k]].push(d[dk[k]])
        }
      }
      return s
    }
  }
  return s.concat(d)
}, [])

console.log(datas2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, if you don't mind I would've liked a little explanation about what you did.

Comment: Yes, what would you like to explain?

Comment: What you did in the loop

Comment: Just check the latest results and current information. to decide whether to add new results or update the latest results.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: @AlyaKra ... the above solution does exactly what was ask for. Thus if it comes to upvoting any solution which was posted within the first 30min after the Q was asked the OP should have considered upvoting/accepting an answer like this and not Karan's attempt.

Comment: I estimated, after testing, that the solution I accepted was very easy to read and understand than the other two.